# Add Tooltip to Chart Legend extjs

Tags: extjs, charts, tooltip, legend

I have a Charts (polar, chartesian) and want to add a tooltip to the legend...

I tried different things, but there is always a bug:

If I do it like this, the tooltip shows up after each element has been selected (IE11, FF, Chrome):

```
legend: { 
           docked: 'right',
           scrollable:'vertical',
           listeners:{
                 itemmouseenter:function( oElem, record, item, index, e, eOpts ){
                                Ext.create("Ext.tip.ToolTip",{
                                    target:item,
                                  //  autoShow:true,
                                    trackMouse:true,
                                    html:record.data.name,
                                    hideDelay:0,
                                    showDelay:0
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

If I add a autoShow:true, it comes always, but in the IE11 the Tooltip is shown twice, one correct and one in the left upper corner. Also in the FF the Tooltip is jumping.

Did just someone tried to make it and did find a good solution?

Comment: Which ExtJS version? Can you recreate the issue in a fiddle? Does it occur in the newest version ExtJS 6.2.1?

Comment: ExtJS version : 5.1.1

Comment: Did you ever get this answered?